# Difference between single op-amp and summing of op-amps

Tags: electric-circuits

I was wondering what differences in performance would there be between
 a single 741 op-amp wired up to provide a gain of $10^6$, and a set of three
741 op-amps, each with a gain of 100, connected in series so as to provide an overall gain of $10^6$.

Comment: This a good candidate for migration to the EE stackexchange.

Comment: I would use instrumentation quality op-amps, not a 741, if used to amplify a signal you want to measure something accurately.

Answer (score 1):

The major parameter you need to look at is Gain-Bandwidth product. If it is (say) 1MHz then you can operate it at 1MHz  at a gain of 1, or a gain of 1000 at 1kHz. It's a tradeoff between gain and bandwidth

That's a bit of an oversimplification, but check out the parameter

Comment: Your answer came through while I was typing mine.

Answer (score 0):

For "ideal" components, there is no difference.

For real components, a multi-stage design gives much more flexibility to control parameters like frequency response, input and output impedance matching, nonlinear component behaviour, etc.

For example the *typical* open-loop gain of a 741 is only $2\times 10^5$ and the *minimum* gain is only $5 \times 10^4$, so a gain of $10^6$ is impossible from a single stage design. (source: data sheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf). On the other hand, a gain of 100 in a single stage is quite possible, at least at low frequencies, even with a low-quality op-amp like a 741.

Without knowing your existing level of electronics knowledge, it's hard to write a longer answer that would be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one easy to see difference.

Physical op-amps have finite gain-bandwidth product which is essentially the frequency at which the open-loop gain is unity.

Assume for this example that an op-amp has a gain-bandwidth product of $1 \mathrm{MHz}$.  This essentially means that

(1) at $1 \mathrm{Hz}$, the open-loop gain is $10^6$

(2) at $1 \mathrm{MHz}$, the open-loop gain is $1$.

(3) the open-loop gain is inversely proportional to frequency from $1\mathrm{Hz}$ to $1\mathrm{MHz}$

Keeping the above in mind, consider that using one such op-amp to produce a gain of $10^6$ implies that the bandwidth is just $1 \mathrm{Hz}$.

However, consider a cascade of three such op-amps configured for closed-loop gains of $100$ each.  Each op-amp circuit will have a bandwidth $10 \mathrm{kHz}$.  The end-to-end gain is $10^6$ like the single op-amp but the bandwidth will be *much* larger - a few $\mathrm{kHz}$.